# CardBuilder show more text

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

is it possible to arrange Show more button using GDK now? I have pretty big portion of text which I would like to split for few cards for example.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with Google Glass is that you can't really "button" in the way that you're thinking. You can't tap on a certain part of the screen. You only can swipe down, up, left, right, and tap.

What you can do, is listen for those possible gestures and then act accordingly - maybe create a `TextBox` that can scroll and scroll through it on the swipes. Or maybe go to the next card/update the text in the card when you tap. Here is how you detect these actions:

You need to create a GestureDetector. Here is how I do it in my projects:

```
public class EXAMPLE {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gestureDetector = createGestureDetector(this);

    }
    private GestureDetector createGestureDetector(Context context) {
        GestureDetector gestureDetectorTemp = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
               return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
               return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent2, float v, float v2) { 
             return false;
            }
        });
        return gestureDetectorTemp;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (gestureDetector != null) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

That last part is very important. On any generic motion event, if the `gestureDetector` isn't null, you'll send the event through the `gestureDetector` for processing.

KEEP IN MIND ALSO that you need to understand what the `return false;` and `return true;` things mean. If you return false, then that means that the event wasn't consumed. If you return true, then the event is consumed. In other words, if you return true, then nothing else will activate, because the event gets 'eaten up,' but if you return false, this sends the event on to other functions which may do something when an action is taken.

Now just take this, and change the `onSingleTapUp()` method's contents to do what you want...something like

```
card.setText(nextSetOfText);
```

or

```
textView.setText(nextSetOfText);
```

You could split your long text into an array of strings with the maximum length that'll fit on the string, then just cycle to the next string in your array when the person taps.

Comment: Any update yet for the question or is it the only way to show long text